# What ways can you secure a web page so that it can ONLY be viewed from within an iFrame?

Tags: security, iframe, vaadin

This thread was created back in 2008  [Restricting IFRAME access in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244952/restricting-iframe-access-in-php)

I am looking to do almost the exact same thing. i.e. I want to have sites which are publicly accessible as long as they are being viewed from a specific iFrame, from a specific app. The IFrame app will have user authentication giving them access to urls outside the core application. The urls are all likely to be built using Open Source PHP tools e.g. Wordpress.

Both the viewing iFrame and the viewed sites/pages will be owned by us.

Have there been any developments in last few years on ways to do this?

For various reasons not related to this particular issue, I am considering using the serverside RIA framework Vaadin (JAVA) for building the app that will contain the iFrame viewer.

The demo of the embed widget is here http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#WebEmbed  Looking at the page source I don't see anywhere that the address of the embedded webpage is displayed. So to some extent I wonder if I can hide my urls from search engines, give them very long, randomly generated URI's and maybe they will be impossible to find anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify a [framekiller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) to do the opposite.  A framekiller is a piece of javascript to prevent clickjacking by detecting if the page has been loaded within an iframe.

Limiting the iframe to load within a specific page is more difficult.  Looking at the referer is easy,  but also easy to bypass.  If you load the iframe from an https page the referer will be blank.  A better way would be to require the server to obtain a Nonce and include this in the iframe url.  Such as `http://iframe_url?key=difhj8j84528423j423894hfdj897` or whatever.   Having the server make a request to your server would be ideal.  Doing it with client side code and jsonp to fetch the nonce is problematic because an attacker could deliver modified javascript to fetch the nonce.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So are you saying this is possible? Using some kind of encryption technique between the server and the apps that sit outside the system.

Comment: Are you also saying that using Vaadin which sits server side would be a better way to go as this is then protected from the client?