# How to prevent my site page from being loaded into other website iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

We have many gaming websites, among them I am hosting exclusive games on my server, and i don't want to access my games to other websites from my server. I want to restrict them accessing my content from my server.

For Example, assume I am having a website called `www.abc.com`, at source path like `www.abc.com/games/abcgame.swf` in which I have hosted my exclusive games. As I want other website holders not to access this content. If they steal this url and trying to access then I want to show some custom message like “Game not found” or somthig like “Please visit `www.abc.com` to play this game.” etc.

Can anyone having any ideas to implement this feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting IFRAME access in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244952/restricting-iframe-access-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A first solution is to use [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header to prevent loading your page to an iframe. [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) can specify one of two values: **`SAMEORIGIN`**, which only
allows iframes from the same origin to display this content, and `deny`, which prevents
any iframe from doing so. BUT this header is not part of HTTP specification and was introduced by Microsoft, so not all browsers support this header. An example of [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options):

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

In case some old browsers don't support the `X-Frame-Options` header. You could try a technique called [FrameKiller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller). There are limitations, though, as pointed out in that link.

> The user agent does not support JavaScript.
>
> The user agent supports JavaScript but the user has turned support off.
>
> The user agent's JavaScript support is flawed or partially implemented.

The idea is to use javascript to detect whether your page is loaded into an iframe. There are many ways to implement a frame killer script.

For your requirement, you could implement a frame killer script like this: try to access your parent window to read the `window.location`. If they include your page inside their iframe, the code would throw exception (cross-domain)

Example code:

```
window.onload = function(){
   try
   {
       if (window.parent && window.parent.location.hostname !== "www.abc.com"){
          throw new Error();
       }
   }
   catch (e){
      alert("Please visit www.abc.com to play this game.");
      //You could do whatever you want here
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried that code but I get DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: @Daniel Soublett: that exception is the purpose of the code

Comment: @Daniel Soublett: that exception means that the iframe is loaded on another domain

Comment: Your javascript won't work. You'd just get an error "Blocked a frame with origin.. from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Comment: @Enrico: That is a frame killer script, getting an error is expected so other websites cannot embed your site in their iframe.

Comment: @Khanh TO Don't think we are on the same page. I mean "error" as in not working in chrome. Use "document.referrer" and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (window.top != window.self) {
                window.top.location = window.self.location;
            }
```

It first checks that the top most frame is the frame itself or not if it is not it changes the top level frame to this one. it is javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this via JavaScript is limited in how it will restrict the content to the browser level. You might be better off Apache `mod_rewrite` to more effectively block content on a server level [as explained here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-mod_rewrite-hot-linking-images-leeching-howto/).

For example, this code you could place in an `.htaccess` file if your server supports it. I am using `www.abc.com` as an example & matching `swf` & `fla` files as an example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?abc.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.(swf|fla)$ - [F]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apache, by looking at the code, I guess this technique relies on http reffer. If that's the case, how can it work if they load our pages in an iframe because the http referrer in this case is our domain for the second request, and null for the first request of an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access **window.parent.location** in chrome. So use **document.referrer** instead.

```
 window.onload = function(){
    
       try
       {
           if (window.parent && document.referrer !== "https://www.yousite.com/"){
           console.log(document.referrer);
    
              throw new Error();
           }
       }
       catch (e){
          window.location.href = "https://yoursite.com";
       }
    
    }
```