# how to block FRAME src from other websites to our website

Tags: javascript, iframe, frameset

I've a question about **FRAMESET**, My website perfectly load on another domains if they use following code.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<META http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET>
<FRAME src="https://www.mywebsite.com" noresize>
<NOFRAMES>
    Your browser does not support frames.
</NOFRAMES>
</FRAMESET>
</HTML>


But this above code doesn't work for other websites. because they already blocked it.
```

Here is my qeustion:

> How can I block this method of FRAMESET that other websites won't be
>   able to load my website into their websites?

As something I know, we can use JavaScript method like  window.top.location.href to redirect other domains to our website if they use FRAMESET, but what's the best solution for this method? Not redirect method, something better way, 
I highly appreciate your help and advice on this issue. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent my site page from being loaded into other website iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800271/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-from-being-loaded-into-other-website-iframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843085/how-to-block-website-from-loading-in-iframe and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800271/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-from-being-loaded-into-other-website-iframe

Comment: For your information, I used <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny"> but it doesn't work, still I can load my website in another domain, and I'm not looking for JavaScript method. so IT'S NOT duplicate question. don't mark it as duplicate

Comment: you tagged the question as a javascript question, that's why it seems like a duplicate. Personally, I'd use `mod_rewrite` in an `.htaccess` file, but that's heavily dependent upon your server setup, hosting, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet)

> Meta-tags that attempt to apply the X-Frame-Options directive DO NOT
>   WORK. For example, )
>   will not work. You must apply the X-FRAME-OPTIONS directive as HTTP
>   Response Header as described above.

In my expierence with PHP it's working when I use for example something like this

```
<?php
header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
```

instead of using a meta tag like

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="SAMEORIGIN">
```

So you have to add your `X-Frame-Options` to header instead of meta tag in HTML head section.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer. this was exactly what I was looking for. now it's working like charm. Thanks